# Is it possible to write 0 into a variable in format string attack?

Tags: c, exploit

I know that %n should be used when we try to overwrite the value of a variable in format string attack. Now I'm wondering whether 0 can be written into a variable in a similar manner. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, why not? https://ideone.com/SGGvYv

Comment: If `%n` is at the beginning of the format string, it will write `0` into the variable.

Comment: @Barmar I think one might also try to do an integer overflow, not sure if it will work with `printf` though